# Bluetooth address is already in use - Raspberry pi

Tags: bluetooth

I want to connect my phone with the raspberry pi via bluetooth and for that, I'm using this code

```
from bluedot.btcomm import BluetoothServer
from signal import pause

def data_received(data):
    print(data)
    s.send(data)

s = BluetoothServer(data_received)
pause()
```

Sometimes It's working fine I'm able to connect my phone and send data but some times its shows error like

```
Bluetooth address B8:27:EB:DA:25:25 is already in use - is the server already running?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypyscript/mainscript.py", line 8, in s = BluetoothServer(data_received)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bluedot/btcomm.py", line 358, in start
    raise e
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I copied this code from [here](https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html#bluetoothserver)

Comment: When you have these issues, did the server not shutdown properly perviously?  Try with this example https://github.com/martinohanlon/BlueDot/blob/master/examples/server_debug.py and see if you get more debug information about what is going wrong.

Comment: Actually, I'm using raspberry pi for one product and there will be no option for end-user to turn off the Bluetooth server manually. The user will directly power off the raspberry pi after work has been done. I find one other way to do it. I'm using for loop with 1 to 5 if there port 1 is in use it will start the server with port 2 same as till port 5. and I tested this code 20 times and it's working perfectly and Thank You for your comment.